# Swift 'While' statement freezing iOS Simulator

Tags: while-loop, swift, control-flow

I'm new to programming and haven't used a 'while' statement in my app before. I've got a cocoapod that is animating a circle timer graphic. When it finishes animating it sets a 'didFinish' BOOL to 'true'. I'm able to successfully check this variable, however when I tell my app to set one of my button labels to a specific text 'while' didFinish is false, its freezes my app.

```
//start the timer and change the label to "Reset"
else {
    brewingTimer.start()
    buttonSelect = 1
    startTimer.setTitle("Reset", forState: .Selected)
    //Start the circle counter graphic
    circleCounterOuter.startWithSeconds(5)
    circleCounterInner.startWithSeconds(2)
    while circleCounterInner.didFinish == false {
        startTimer.setTitle("Reset!", forState: .Selected)
    }
    startTimer.setTitle("Ok!", forState: .Selected)
}
```

The moment I tap 'start' the app freezes. When set a break point for the de-bugger at my while-loop, the app appears to loop through my statement as I can click to 'step over' as it loops through the 'while-loop'. But while I am de-bugging I of course cannot see my animation running on screen, so I'm not sure what's actually happening to cause the sluggish simulation.

Comment: Try adding a debugging line inside your while loop to track the seconds remaining in your timer. I suspect it may not even be counting  down.

Comment: What cocoapod are you using? It seems very odd that a timer library would not supply a delegate or completion block. While loops to constantly poll on the main thread are never the right answer.

Comment: The cocoapod is JWGCircleCounter. It notes at the bottom that I can inspect the "didFinish property. Perhaps I need to set up a delegate to listen for this change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code blocks the main thread.

This code is busy executing over and over again:

```
while circleCounterInner.didFinish == false {
    startTimer.setTitle("Reset!", forState: .Selected)
}
```

Meanwhile, nothing else on the main thread can do anything (like update text or respond to touch events) so your app appears to be frozen.

Try a different patten. For example, set the `startTimer` label when the long-running work begins. Then, in a different method update the button when the work has been completed.

You may want to read up on the *delegation* and *notification* design patterns, which are commonly used in situations like this.

Comment: I think what I am struggling with is how to have my view controller constantly listen for `circleCounterInner.didFinish == true`. I've got a function declared in my view controller class with an if statement checking the 'didFinish' value, but the view controller needs to "always" run this function. I thought that was the point of a `while` statement - that the loop would be running off in memory somewhere while my code continued to evaluate. I didn't realize that it stopped all other execution until the statement evaluated false.

Comment: In Objective-C, you could use Key-Value Observation to notify your view controller whenever `didFinish` changes. To my knowledge, there's no equivalent in Swift, so you'll need to use delegation, notifications, or a completion handler to tell your view controller every time you update this variable.